# GCC linker : passing multiple --wrap=<function>

Tags: gcc, linker, cmocka

I am adding quite a few mocks, using [cmocka](https://cmocka.org/), which require me to alias them using the GC Clinker opetion `--wrap=`

I am passing a linker option of the format

```
-Wl,--wrap=foo,--wrap=bar,--wrap=baz,--wrap= ...
```

Is there any way to shorten it?

`-Wl,--wrap=foo,bar,baz,...` did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to shorten it?

No.

Why would you want to? If you care about the length of the resulting command line, note that GCC supports response files:

```
echo "-Wl,--wrap=foo,--wrap=bar,--wrap=baz,--wrap=..." > cmd
gcc @cmd ...
```

Comment: I could foresee it becoming veeeeerrrrrrrry long, but your response file is a great answer. Long you may you continue to be employed :-)